# Single view of Custom Post Type shows home page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a simple post type `lessons`

```
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Lessons', 'Post Type General Name', 'open-college' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lesson', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'open-college' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Lessons', 'open-college' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Lesson:', 'open-college' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Lessons', 'open-college' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'open-college' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'open-college' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'open-college' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'description'         => __( 'An Open College lesson', 'open-college' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'comments', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    register_post_type( 'lesson', $args );
```

The problem I have is, when I create a new lesson named "My Example Lesson", it says I can view it at `/lesson/my-example-lesson/`, but when I navigate to that URL, I just see the home page...

I tried updating the permalinks, even removing mod_rewrite and accessing using `?lesson=my-example-lesson`, but still it just displays the home page.

`single.php` doesn't even get called, it's using the index file.

Comment: create single-lesson.php

Comment: I created it, and it doesn't get called, if that file doesn't exist, it defaults to call single.php, which also doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I found the problem! I have my hooks divided for frontend and backend, I was only registering the custom type on the backend, so when I ran from the frontend WordPress didn't find the custom post type.